# One-tailed hypothesis test of the difference between two population variances

Tags: hypothesis-testing, f-test

My hypothesis is that the difference between two population variances is greater than X.  Please note that I am not asking if the difference is equal to zero.  The solution should also apply to the difference between two population variances being less than some stated value.

If I was interested in the difference between two population means, I would add my hypothesized difference to the difference between the mean of sample 1 and the mean of sample 2.  I cannot do this for my variance test because the F statistic is based on the ratio of the two sample variances, not the difference between them.

I cannot find any discussions of this problem on the Internet or in multiple statistics textbooks.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why are you interested in a difference between variances instead of a ratio? Nothing is inherently wrong with that, but it does feel less natural.

Comment: There is something wrong with that hypothesis: without very strong distributional assumptions, it's not testable.  In most applications it would be meaningless.  Consider what it means for the two variances to be, say, 0.01 and 1 compared to what it means for them to be 99.01 and 100.  The former two are far apart whereas the latter two are practically indistinguishable, even though the differences are the same in both cases.

Comment: For example, a project team believes that a revision to the current process will reduce output variability by x units per batch, which can be converted to standard deviations and thus to a measurable reduction in the variance.  Random samples of the current and the proposed processes are selected and the sample variance of each are noted.  What hypothesis test can we use to reject, or fail to reject, the null hypothesis that the population variances differ by x or more?